# ".htaccess" AuthType Basic to AuthType Digest

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a problem converting my AuthType Basic method to AuthType Digest method. I am really not sure how to get started.

This is my htaccess files, I have 3 pages which only specified users can access it. However I want to change the AuthType Basic to AuthType Digest but it is giving me an error.

```
AuthUserFile "/xampp/htdocs/lab1/.htpasswd"
AuthName "Please log in"
AuthType Basic

<Files A1.htm>
require user John
</Files>
<Files A2.htm>
require user John Nancy
</Files>
<Files A3.htm>
require user Randy
</Files>


.htpasswd
John:123
Nancy:123
Randy:123
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do more than just change your `AuthType` from `Basic` to `Digest`. You need to create a new htpassword file using the [**htdigest** tool](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htdigest.html).

See this [tutorial](http://tuxtuts.com/how-to-setup-htdigest-authentication-for-apache-httpd/) for more information.